# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '='. How do I Insert into new table using case from other table?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case, multiple-columns, insert-into

I am working split a column that contains all the data into multiple columns. I am using the CASE condition to do so and with the INSERT INTO I have had trouble successfully achieving the task. I think I may need another SELECT statement but I am not sure where.

```
USE Breakthroughapp;
GO
INSERT INTO Lineup_possessions (m_player, g_time, g_scorefor, g_scoreagainst, g_event)

    SELECT
    (m_player =                                     
    CASE                                                                        
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Walter'     THEN 'N Walter'                     
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%B. Fish%'      THEN 'B Fish'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Wiese'      THEN 'M Wiese'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%C. Stekl'      THEN 'C Stekl'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%R. Whalen'     THEN 'R Whalen'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Pflughaupt' THEN 'M Pflughaupt'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%T. Kuethe'     THEN 'T Kuethe'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%O. Carstensen' THEN 'O Carstensen'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%I. Hahn'       THEN 'I Hahn'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Schmidt'    THEN 'N Schmidt'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Marion%'       THEN 'Team'
    WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Game Clock%'   THEN 'Official'                     
    ELSE 'Opponent'
    END ,
   g_time,  -- New Column
   g_ptsfor, 
   g_pointsagainst,
   (g_event =
   CASE
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Entered%'               THEN 'Enter Game'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Exited%'                THEN 'Exit Game'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Started%'     THEN 'Clock Starts Rolling'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Stopped%'     THEN 'Clock Stoppage'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Made%'            THEN 'Layup Made' 
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Made%'              THEN '2 pt Made'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Made%'              THEN '3 pt Made'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Miss%'            THEN 'Layup Miss'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Miss%'              THEN '2 pt Miss'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Miss%'              THEN '3 pt Miss'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Made%'       THEN 'FT Made'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Miss'        THEN 'FT Miss'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Foul%'                  THEN 'Foul'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Defensive Rebound%' THEN 'Defensive Rebound'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Offensive Rebound%' THEN 'Offensive Rebound'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Forced Jump Ball%'      THEN 'Forced Jump Ball'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Assist%'                THEN 'Assist'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Steal%'             THEN 'Steal'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Block%'             THEN 'Block'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Timeout%'               THEN 'Timeout'
   WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Turnover%'              THEN 'Turnover'
   ELSE 'Other'
   END)
```

FROM FakeGameCorrect;

Comment: Try removing the `()`

Comment: That does not work. I believe there needs to be the separation with () but there needs to be a SELECT statement or something to separate everything.

Comment: Not the `()` from the `INSERT` but the `()` from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Or you can just add the missing `)` on your `m_player`.

Comment: I have tried all of that but it continues to return the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `()`:

```
INSERT INTO Lineup_possessions (m_player, g_time, g_scorefor, g_scoreagainst, g_event)

SELECT
    m_player =                                     
        CASE                                                                        
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Walter'     THEN 'N Walter'                     
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%B. Fish%'      THEN 'B Fish'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Wiese'      THEN 'M Wiese'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%C. Stekl'      THEN 'C Stekl'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%R. Whalen'     THEN 'R Whalen'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Pflughaupt' THEN 'M Pflughaupt'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%T. Kuethe'     THEN 'T Kuethe'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%O. Carstensen' THEN 'O Carstensen'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%I. Hahn'       THEN 'I Hahn'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Schmidt'    THEN 'N Schmidt'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Marion%'       THEN 'Team'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Game Clock%'   THEN 'Official'                     
            ELSE 'Opponent'
        END ,
    g_time,  -- New Column
    g_ptsfor, 
    g_pointsagainst,
    g_event =
        CASE
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Entered%'              THEN 'Enter Game'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Exited%'               THEN 'Exit Game'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Started%'        THEN 'Clock Starts Rolling'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Stopped%'        THEN 'Clock Stoppage'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Made%'           THEN 'Layup Made' 
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Made%'             THEN '2 pt Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Made%'             THEN '3 pt Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Miss%'           THEN 'Layup Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Miss%'             THEN '2 pt Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Miss%'             THEN '3 pt Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Made%'      THEN 'FT Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Miss'       THEN 'FT Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Foul%'                 THEN 'Foul'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Defensive Rebound%'    THEN 'Defensive Rebound'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Offensive Rebound%'    THEN 'Offensive Rebound'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Forced Jump Ball%'     THEN 'Forced Jump Ball'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Assist%'               THEN 'Assist'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Steal%'                THEN 'Steal'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Block%'                THEN 'Block'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Timeout%'              THEN 'Timeout'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Turnover%'             THEN 'Turnover'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END
FROM FakeGameCorrect;
```

Or if you really want to use `()`, it should be placed after the `=` sign:

```
INSERT INTO Lineup_possessions (m_player, g_time, g_scorefor, g_scoreagainst, g_event)

SELECT
    m_player = (                                     
        CASE                                                                        
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Walter'     THEN 'N Walter'                     
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%B. Fish%'      THEN 'B Fish'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Wiese'      THEN 'M Wiese'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%C. Stekl'      THEN 'C Stekl'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%R. Whalen'     THEN 'R Whalen'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%M. Pflughaupt' THEN 'M Pflughaupt'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%T. Kuethe'     THEN 'T Kuethe'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%O. Carstensen' THEN 'O Carstensen'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%I. Hahn'       THEN 'I Hahn'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%N. Schmidt'    THEN 'N Schmidt'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Marion%'       THEN 'Team'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Game Clock%'   THEN 'Official'                     
            ELSE 'Opponent'
        END
    ),
    g_time,  -- New Column
    g_ptsfor, 
    g_pointsagainst,
    g_event = (
        CASE
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Entered%'              THEN 'Enter Game'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Exited%'               THEN 'Exit Game'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Started%'        THEN 'Clock Starts Rolling'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Clock Stopped%'        THEN 'Clock Stoppage'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Made%'           THEN 'Layup Made' 
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Made%'             THEN '2 pt Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Made%'             THEN '3 pt Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Layup Miss%'           THEN 'Layup Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%2pt Miss%'             THEN '2 pt Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%3pt Miss%'             THEN '3 pt Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Made%'      THEN 'FT Made'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Free Throw Miss'       THEN 'FT Miss'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Foul%'                 THEN 'Foul'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Defensive Rebound%'    THEN 'Defensive Rebound'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Offensive Rebound%'    THEN 'Offensive Rebound'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Forced Jump Ball%'     THEN 'Forced Jump Ball'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Assist%'               THEN 'Assist'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Steal%'                THEN 'Steal'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Block%'                THEN 'Block'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Timeout%'              THEN 'Timeout'
            WHEN g_playbyplay LIKE '%Turnover%'             THEN 'Turnover'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END
    )
FROM FakeGameCorrect;
```